# How Use Object of Linq to SQL in new request in C#

Tags: c#, android, ajax, cordova, model-view-controller

I am relatively new in MVC and C#, and i am having a lot of problems to learn some little things. I am having some errors and would like any help to solve my problem.
I have these 2 models:

UsuarioDal:

```
    public Usuario LoginById(int Id)
    {
        var login = (from u in db.Usuario
                     where u.IdUsuario == Id && u.Ativo == true
                     select u).FirstOrDefault();
        return login;
    }
```

UsuarioDeviceDal:

```
    public UsuarioDevice getByUUID(string uuid)
    {
        var usuariodevice = (from c in db.UsuarioDevice
                      where c.UuId == uuid
                      select c).FirstOrDefault();
        return usuariodevice;
    }
```

Controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetConsultaLogUsu(string uuid){
        UsuarioDeviceDAL dev = new UsuarioDeviceDAL();
        UsuarioDAL obj = new UsuarioDAL();

        var device = dev.getByUUID(uuid);
        var usu obj.LoginById(device.IdUsuario); // this is the line that i would like to work.

        if (device != null){ 
        return new HttpResponseMessage(){
                Content = new StringContent("L")
            };
        }else{
            return new HttpResponseMessage(){
                Content = new StringContent("D")
            };
        }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
function fn_verificalog() {
var uuid = $("#uuid").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: linkServidor + "api/GuardaUsuario/GetConsultaLogUsu?uuid="+uuid,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        navigator.notification.alert(data, fn_ErroApp(), "Sucesso teste.");
        if (data === 'L') {
            window.location.href = "verdelandia.html";
        }             
    },
    error: function () {
        navigator.notification.alert("Estamos verificando o problema.", fn_ErroApp(), "Ocorreu um problema.");
    }
});
```

}

If someone have any idea of how to solve that, i would stay really grateful. Thank you everyone with try to help.

Comment: `I am having some errors`  Which errors you have?

Comment: Thank you for your question. He ever fall in the error message of ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did couple things in your `ajax` configuration:

- Removed `contentType: "application/json"` because you sending only query string. By default `contentType` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.
- Instead to manually configure query string parameter I added as `data` option.
- I added parameters in `error` handler and you will be able to inspect which error you have.

Please see how it looks in your case:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: linkServidor + "api/GuardaUsuario/GetConsultaLogUsu",
        data: {
            'uuid': uuid
        },
        success: function(data) {
            navigator.notification.alert(data, fn_ErroApp(), "Sucesso teste.");
            if (data === 'L') {
                window.location.href = "verdelandia.html";
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            navigator.notification.alert("Estamos verificando o problema.", fn_ErroApp(), "Ocorreu um problema.");
        }
    });
```

Instead to creating URL as string you can try to use [action helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { uuid= "<uuid>" })
```